# How to replace an image source during the run time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very strange issue in my app.

I have something like the following.

Series of image files

```
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png
image4.png
image5.png
…more
```

JS

```
var inter = window.setInterval(function(){play()},300);

function play(){
  $('#holder').attr('src','image'+index+'.png')
   index++;
   if(index==20){
       clearInterval(inter);  
   }
}
```

The idea is to play a series of image and make it looks like an animation. It totally works in my and two other computers on chrome.

However, certain computers with the same chrome version can't seem to display each image. The image file change in the run time but the browser only show the first image and it only happens in some computers.

I really can't figure out what happen. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks so much!

Comment: On the computers where it fails, are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's the case here but I had a similiar issue once, because images did not load in time. Try preloading them.

Link with some info:
http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to change an images src.  Just use basic JavaScript.

Here is a simple example: **http://jsfiddle.net/D232R/2/**

```
<input type="button" value="change image" onclick="changeImage()">
<br>
<img id="img1" src="http://i24.photobucket.com/albums/c42/papayacrazy/gifs/tumblr_ma9phigvTK1rxw3fco1_500.gif">

<script>
  changeImage=function()
  {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = "http://i756.photobucket.com/albums/xx202/Blairewolfe/fail.jpg";
  }
</script>
```

But if it's a loading issue I suppose you could load them all, add `display:none;` to all of them, then just cycle though them using `jQuery.toggle()` **http://api.jquery.com/toggle/**

**UPDATE:**

Here is a fiddle for the toggle method: **http://jsfiddle.net/N9r5y/1/**  You could also add some nice fade if you want.

Here it is with some easing: **http://jsfiddle.net/N9r5y/2/**

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using css sprites, particularly if your images are small.  This would enable your browser to download just one larger image instead of many small ones.

You'd reformat all your single, smaller images into one larger one. You then use css to change the img element's properties to display just the appropriate image fragment. There are several free online versions around that would help you create your image file.

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ has a good explanation of the technique and some links to online tools.